# DataFrame slicing and default index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas.DataFrame df as shown below. The first column are the auto-generated indexes.

```
In[221]: df
Out[220]: 
    name  age sex        job
0   John   15   M    Student
1   Mike   30   M      Labor
2   Lily   41   F    Student
3   Dave   66   M      Labor
4    Sam   23   F  Scientist
5   Luke    7   M      Labor
6  Ellen   80   F      Labor
7  Jacob   52   M      Actor
```

Now after I slice it, the default indexes are inherited.

```
In[225]: df_labor = df[df.job == 'Labor']
In[226]: df_labor
Out[225]: 
    name  age sex    job
1   Mike   30   M  Labor
3   Dave   66   M  Labor
5   Luke    7   M  Labor
6  Ellen   80   F  Labor
```

Since the auto-generated indexes mean nothing to me. How do make them [0, 1, 2, 3] instead of [1, 3, 5, 6], such that when I try to get the 3rd (zero based) row of df_labor with df_labor.ix[3]['name'], I can get 'Ellen' instead of 'Dave'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call [reset_index](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df_labor = df[df.job == "Labor"].reset_index(drop = True)
In [94]: df_labor               
Out[94]:                

    age job     name    sex
0   30  Labor   Mike    M
1   66  Labor   Dave    M
2   7   Labor   Luke    M
3   80  Labor   Ellen   F
```

By default, pandas adds the old index as a column to the new dataframe. `drop = True` drops that column.